Isekai manga in which the main character was given a ring from an assassin group to contact them and join them in assassinating the queen/goddess
I forgot how it started but IIRC the main character was given a ring from an assassin group to contact them and to join them in assassinating the queen/goddess. He then was able to defeat dragon riders(? I don't know if this one is in it since it wasn't in the Failure Frame manga). He then found an item with an ego; I don't know what item that was. When he's overly strong, he joined the assassin group and one tapped the goddess/queen with overpowered magic. He revived and killed her several times, then, when they're done and he came back, his friend was helping the town to defeat a stampede and he asked his item to give him wings and he was given black wings.

Nito's Lazy Foreign World Syndrome (AKA Nito no Taidana Isekai Shoukougun: Saijaku Shoku "Healer" nano ni Saikyou wa Cheat desu ka?)

Hidako Masamune is a high school student who suffers from continuous bullying by his classmates. Becoming tired of it all, he decides to commit suicide, but instead he is transported to another world along with all his classmates. When they arrive, they find that they now possess amazing abilities but he was only granted the status of a "healer," the weakest skill of all. The king decides to get rid of him by transporting him to another far away place, but not before Hidako swears revenge against the king, the kingdom, and all of his classmates.

At one point Nito gets a communication ring from the 'Assassination Squad'. He kills the king/princess who summoned him. He also has a talking staff.
